# LocationManager crashing on OnFormShow after turn Off/On LocationSensor

Tags: android, delphi, location, delphi-10.1-berlin, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm using a native location manager but if I turn off the Location sensor and then turn On again, the app keeps crashing right after is launched (the Location Sensor icon just blink). However, if I mock a new location then it doesn't crash and works perfect.

Ps.: also, while the app keeps crashing at launch, if I run Waze, wait for 10 seconds, and then launch again, it works.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  Androidapi.JNI.Location, Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os, FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListBox, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, Androidapi.Helpers;

type

  TLocationListener = class;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FLocationManager : JLocationManager;
    locationListener : TLocationListener;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
  end;

  TLocationListener = class(TJavaLocal, JLocationListener)
  private
    [weak]
    FParent : TForm1;
  public
    constructor Create(AParent : TForm1);
    procedure onLocationChanged(location: JLocation); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderDisabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderEnabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer; extras: JBundle); cdecl;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;

{ TLocationListener }

constructor TLocationListener.Create(AParent: TForm1);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FParent := AParent;
end;

procedure TLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
begin
  FParent.onLocationChanged(location);
end;

procedure TLocationListener.onProviderDisabled(provider: JString);
begin

end;

procedure TLocationListener.onProviderEnabled(provider: JString);
begin

end;

procedure TLocationListener.onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer;
  extras: JBundle);
begin

end;

{ TForm1 }

destructor TForm1.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(locationListener) then
    FLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  LocationManagerService: JObject;
  location : JLocation;
begin
  if not Assigned(FLocationManager) then
  begin
    LocationManagerService := SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap((LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    if not Assigned(locationListener) then
      locationListener := TLocationListener.Create(self);
    FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 20, locationListener,TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);
  end;
  location := FLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  onLocationChanged(location);
end;

procedure TForm1.onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
begin
 Label1.Text := FloatToStr((location.getSpeed*3600)/1000) + ' km/h';
end;

end.
```

What am I missing? Which part of the event may be causing this crash?

Comment: Without indicating exactly where it is crashing, and/or a call stack, it's hard to say

Comment: It crashed during the black screen after the splash screen, the Location icon just blink and the app closes. I solved by removing these two lines:

location := LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation (TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  onLocationChanged(location);

But then, it doesn't trigger the LocationChange until the phone change its location from actual.

Comment: Did you use the debugger to work out whether it was actually crashing on the line(s) you removed?

Comment: Actually I can't use a debugger because my phone doesn't communicate to the PC through USB anymore and there is no SSD space. I have to copy each .apk to the phone through Wi-Fi :(

Comment: I solved it by moving these two lines `location := FLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  onLocationChanged(location);` to `OnFormPaint` and setting a boolean variable so it happens only once (after app is launched). Sorry I'm asking too much things lately.

Comment: Why not just move all the code in OnShow, into an overridden Create? In any event, I plan to have a deeper look into this soon